# How can I change the login link to logout when customer logged in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, customer, footer-links

I have added a login link in the footer by cms like as:

```
    <a href="{{store url="customer/account/login"}}">Login</a>
```

As soon as customer login I want to change that in the Logout link in magento2 footer.

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to theme xml file?

Comment: Yes  i have access .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Go to content -> Blocks -> "Footer Links Block"

Edit and add this link into content editor (below customer service link)

```
<li class="nav item">{{block class="CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Footer" template="CompanyName_ModuleName::footer.phtml"}}</li>
```

and save it.

Create **Footer.php** block at `CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\`

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Block;

class Footer extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Check customer Login or not
     */
    public function checkCustomerLogin()
    {
        $customer_data = [];
        if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customer_data['text'] = "Login";
            $customer_data['url'] = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/login');
        } else {
            $customer_data['text'] = "Logout";
            $customer_data['url'] = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('customer/account/logout');
        }
        return $customer_data;
    }
}
```

Now, create **footer.phtml** file at `/app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates` and add this code

```
<?php $customerData = $block->checkCustomerLogin(); ?>

<a href="<?php echo $customerData['url'];?>"><?php echo $customerData['text'];?></a>
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: I tried it but i am getting logout link in footer even i am not logged in

Comment: can you update this if ($this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) to if (!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) in your answer ?

Comment: Your answer is working best :)

Comment: Can you update this @Rohan Then will accept this answer ?

Comment: Oh Yes..!! It's by mistake. Thanks :). Now, Updated

Comment: When I turn on the cache, it doesn't work correctly. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Using below code you can check if customer is logged in or not.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager $om */
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context */
$context = $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context');
/** @var bool $isLoggedIn */
$isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
```

So you can write code conditionally. If already logged in, show logout link otherwise login link.

You can call such phtml template in cms page as below

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YourTemplateFileLocation].phtml"}}
```

Comment: I can use above code if i am using phtml file , how can i use that code in cms page admin ?

Comment: I updated answer to call phtml in cms page

Comment: I have tried by phtml but due to cache footer does not check dynamic conditions . Its need cache flush then its display effect.

Comment: Use my given code. It will work also when cache is enabled.

Comment: my project manager does not allowing me to use
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); in phtml file

Comment: You can convert that code using Block and constructer in class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81033/discussion-between-ansar-husain-and-kishan-patadia).

Answer (score 1):

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_links">
    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login" template="account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

This will place the same link in the footer which is on header. Put in your default.xml. This will place the link in the second column. I have not checked for First column.